# Relationship between the fundamental group and the natural equivalence classes of its universal cover

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

For a universal covering $p: Y \to X$, under the equivalence relation $y_1 \sim y_2$ if $p(y_1) = p(y_2)$, $Y$ admits the quotient map $\, \, \, q: Y \to Y / \sim$. There is a natural bijection $\bar p : Y / \sim \, \,  \to X$ and according to a few wikipedia examples there is an isomorphic relationship between the fundamental group of $X$ and the equivalence classes. One such example from wikipedia is

> The universal cover of a circle $S^1$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and we have $S^1
>  = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $\pi_1(S^1, x) = \mathbb{Z}$ for any base point $x$.

Is this obvious as wikipedia seems to suggest it is, if so can someone please explain why? If not could someone please prove this?

EDIT: From the answers it seems my exact questions is not clear; I understand the concept of a universal cover and the fact it comes down to finding a simply connecting covering. My questions is focusing on why, in the example, $\pi_1(S^1, x) = \mathbb{Z}$ ? Does this generalise ot the equivalence relation  I've defined in the first paragraph?

Comment: I think your first sentence doesn't quite make sense...

Comment: I think you've stumbled upon the Galois correspondence for converings. This is a special case of a very useful adjunction that comes up in many places other than "proper" Galois theory: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Algebraic_topology:_covering_spaces"> Wikipedia </a> always helps. Also, your phrasing is not very clear in the first paragraph, at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial, just known. If $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a covering map and E is path connected, $b\in B, e\in p^{-1}(b) $ then we can define $F:\pi_1(B,b)\rightarrow p^{-1}(b)$ by $F([\varphi])=\hat \varphi ^e(1)$, where $\hat \varphi ^e(1)$ is the unique path in E which is the lift of $\varphi$ and starts at $e$. It's well defined since if two paths have a base-point preserving homotopy, then their lifts end at the same point. Also, F is surjective, and if $E$ is also simply connected, then F is bijective. Now, in our case of $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1 , p(t)=e^{2\pi i t}, p^{-1}(1)=\mathbb{Z}$ F is also a group homomorphism and hence an isomoprhism. Notice that it only applies to the circle - we don't generalize this, but use different means based on this result (e.g. Van Kampen).

Answer (score 0):

Finding the universal cover of $X$ just comes down to finding a simply connected space which covers $X$. One of the prototypical examples of a covering map is the map $p\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ given by the exponential function, and given that $\mathbb{R}$ is a contractible space, it is certainly simply connected. It follows that $\mathbb{R}$ is a covering space for the circle $S^1$.

You might like the try and convince yourself that the sphere $S^2$ is its own universal cover. Just remember the definition of a universal cover.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is trivial if you already know the answer.
But, perhaps, what you wish to know is about "covering action" of groups.
If you have an action satisfying some properties, you have a universal covering corresponding to this action. It is the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting in the real line and it is the case of $\mathbb{Z}_2 $ acting on the sphere (and you getting the projective plane).

You need some conditions... I assume that you know what is an action of a group.
Let $G$ be a group and $X$ be a topological space.
Assume that $G$ acts on $X$ such that $p: X\to X/G$ is a covering. Then you have that $ Aut (p) = G $. And, more, $p$ is a regular/normal covering.

In the case of circumference, we have that $\mathbb{Z}$ acts in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} $ is a covering map. Then you can conclude that $Aut(p)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. But, since $p$ is a universal convering, $\pi _1(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}, \ast )\cong Aut(p)$.

Same for the sphere!

Comment: Perhaps, I should add a comment. I don't know whether you already saw that, but all coverings are quotient maps. And your associated quotient map is, nothing more, than the covering itself. How do you see that? Well, all coverings are open maps: in particular, all coverings are quotient maps. Your quotient has the same fibers: so it is homeomorphic to the original one... You need to have in mind that what characterizes a quotient are its fibers.

Comment: I have some related answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214742/covering-space-and-fundamental-group/356548#356548 and at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361248/quotient-space-and-retractions/361945#361945