# Quotient space and Retractions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to learn something about topology and category theory.
Let us consider the category of compact Polish spaces. The category contains all quotients of all objects ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space))

For an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X\times X$, we denote with $X/\!\sim$ the quotient space and with $q:X\rightarrow X/\!\sim$ the quotient map.

I'm trying to convince myself that if $\sim$ is induced by a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ (i.e., $x\sim x^\prime$ iff $f(x)=f(x^{\prime}$), then $X/\!\sim$ is a retraction of $X$.

**QUESTION 1** How do one formalize within category theory that a quotient is induced by a map in the category, and not by an arbitrary set-theoretic relation (which is looks as an external concept)?

**QUESTION 2** As I said I'm trying to prove that $X/\!\sim$ is a retract of $X$. For this I should basically construct a continuous function (a "section") $s: X/\!\sim\rightarrow X$ such that $q\circ s=id$. The natural candidate is $s([x]_{\sim})=x$ for some chosen $x$ "representing" the equivalence class. Of course I can construct a set-function with this property. But how to prove that it is continuous?

**QUESTION 3** Under what hypothesis a functor $F$ preserve quotients? Both in general and in the particular case of $F$ an endofunctor in compact Polish spaces.

An interesting functor is $\textbf{V}$, the Vietoris functor mapping $X$ to the space of its compact subsets which in Compact Polish spaces are precisely the closed sets with the hit-miss topology. This is interesting because the points in $\mathbb{V}(X)$ are closed sets, hence, $V(X)$ somehow topologies the (complement of the) topology on $X$ !

**QUESTION 4** As a particular case of question 3 above, does $\mathbb{V}(X)$ preserve quotients?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It is certainly not true that every quotient is a retract. If you identify $0$ and $1$ in $[0,1]$ you get a circle, but this circle is not a retract of the interval. The equivalence relation is induced by the continuous function $f(x) = \exp(2\pi i x)$

Comment: Question 1: You could say that it is an [effective epimorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism), or even an [extremal epimorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extremal+epimorphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several ways to formulate quotient concept using category theory... But you can adopt one depending on your interest.
But, first of all, I guess you have to understand the concept all by itself (in topology).
Note that it is not true that all quotients are retractions... Let $ I = \left[ 0,1\right] $ be the closed interval and $ S^1 $ be the circumference.
You have an obvious quotient map $ q: I\to S^1 $. Note that this is not a retraction!!

You can see that there is no section for $ q $, using the categorical fact that sections in the category of Top are point set injections, since Top is a concrete category. (using, here, a theorem such as weak Borsuk Ulam: there isn't any continuous injection $S^1\to\mathbb{R}$)

To answer question 3, you need to think in a way of answering question 1. One way of doing so is thinking a quotient as a particular pushout.
So a functor preserves "quotient" when functors preserves this kind of pushout.

I haven't knew about this functor... But you can check if it is left adjoint or preserves some kind of pushouts.

To understand quotient in the categorical sense in a nontrivial way, you can do as following:
If $q: X\to Y $ is a quotient map, let  $U(X) $ be the space $X$ with the discrete topology. And let $A$ be the space of fibers of $q$ with discrete topology too, id est, $A = \left\{ q^{-1}(x) : x\in Y \right\} $ with discrete topology.
Note that you have  obvious morphisms $U(X)\to A$ and $U(X)\to X $. 
The pushout of these morphisms is what you want: the quotient (for us, here, it is $Y$).... 
It is, too, a nice way to see that the quotient is determined by the fibers and the total space (nothing more than this).
But, as I said, there are many other ways to view this in categorical language: and, perhaps, this way doesn't satisfy what you want - the best way to see depends of what you want.

Comment: About the second question, take a look at coverings. If a covering is not a homeomorphism, it is a quotient map which is not a retraction. Why?
Because retraction is preserved by functors - and, therefore, if a covering is a retraction, we would have a surjection between the fundamental groups. Since it is already a injection (because p is a covering), p induces a isomorphism of fundamental groups - and this implies that the covering is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I forgot to sayt that coverings are quotient maps because they are (surjective) open maps. 
I proved, here, that if a covering is a retraction, then this covering is a homeomorphism.